# MySQL timestamp record being updated but affected rows remains 0

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, timestamp, laravel

There are a few similar questions but I'll throw this in the mix.

Basically, I have a timestamp column (which is an **int**) and one of my updates is ONLY updating this timestamp column and sometimes it's a barely noticeable distance. For instance, it might change from 1316631442 to 1316631877. Not really much of a difference between the two.

So the record is being updated, I can check in phpMyAdmin before the query is run and then afterward and see the difference. However, I'm doing a var_dump() on the affected row count and it remains 0.

If I update another column at the same time to a different value then the affected rows are 1.

So what does it take to trigger the row as being affected? Even though it's being affected since the update is successful.

Also, I'm using the Laravel PHP framework and its query builder. Currently doing a bit of debugging in there to see if something may be off but so far all seems to be well.

EDIT: Sorry I had mistyped something above. When I completely change another column's value the affected rows is 1, not 0.

Comment: Is the row being updated by `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or explicitly being set by your query?

Comment: It's being explicitly set via the query, with PHP's time() if that makes a difference.

Comment: Any chance your framework is doing another query on its own after the update?

Comment: @ceejayoz My thoughts exactly.

Comment: @ceejayoz I've dumped the array of queries that were executed AFTER running this query and it's the last one listed so it's not running another query.

Comment: I had a mistype in my question. When I make changes to another column at the same time and completely change its value the affected rows is 1. So it's only with the timestamp changing that I encounter this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those curious I resorted to using an INSERT INTO... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to achieve the desired result. I still couldn't figure out why MySQL wasn't reporting the record as being affected.

I also tried using PHPs mysql_query() and related functions to check the affected row but it didn't work like that also. Perhaps MySQL doesn't deem the change to be worthy of marking the record as affected.

Answer (score 0):

I can replicate the issue with MySql 5.1 but not with Mysql 5.7.

In the earlier version

```
UPDATE `test`
SET
    `time` = TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, 10, NOW())
WHERE
    `id = 1
```

does update the timestamp but the message is that zero rows have been affected.

With the later version of MySql the same query gives me one row affected.

It seems to be a MySql bug that has been fixed.

Time to get the Server admin to update some stuff?